# How can I assign when a key/combination of keys is pressed in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to assign multiple functions for the same shortcut keys but those functions will not run simultaneously. I am using Tkinter.

For example, I have two frames on the root window `left_frame` and `right_frame`. In the left frame, I have two buttons 1 and 2 and in the right frame, I have 1 button namely 1. This button is hidden with the help of `place_forget()`. So when I click on the button 1 in the left frame,  the button on the right frame is displayed with name for example, `1.1`. Similarly, when I click on button 2 in the left frame, the button on the right frame is displayed with name for example, `2.1`. When button 1 is pressed, the button on the right frame has a different command not in relation to the command assigned for the same button on the right frame when button 2 is pressed on the left frame. In simpler words, though the button is the same one but the functions for `1.1` and `2.1` are different. Up to this, I have achieved my desire comfortably.

Now, what I want to do is assign a common shortcut for both  `1.1` and `2.1`. Suppose I have assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as a shortcut through the `bind()` method, so what I want is when I have clicked button 1 on the left frame, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then it should trigger the function for `1.1` but if I do the same thing after I have pressed button2 in the left frame, the function for `2.1` should be triggered.

EDIT:

This is my parent window:
[image]

When I click on Student Details, the following buttons open up on the right side:

[image]

When I click on Block/Room Details, the following buttons open up on the right side:

[image]

Now I want to assign the same key combinations as shortcuts to open Add Student and Add Block, i.e., after clicking on the Student Details button, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then the function for `Add Student` will be triggered. But if I do the same thing when I have clicked on Block Details, then the function for `Add Block` should be triggered.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? So we can understand better? `bind` is used to sort of trigger a function, here you are asking to click a button, which indeed triggers a function and then use ctrl+c? I dont understand the point.

Comment: Check out this [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html) for how to specify keys in tKinter

Comment: You can rebind `Ctrl-C` key after switching frame.

Comment: @acw1668: Can you please elaborate the process?

Comment: As you click a button on the left frame, you will update the right frame.  So after updating the right frame, bind `Ctrl-C` to the function you want.

Comment: @acw1668: So I need to do the binding in the command for a button in the left frame. Am I right?

Comment: It is hard to say as we don't have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).